# How can I test if a div is blocked

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

How can I test if some div is blocked ?

I'm using BlockUI plugin.

```
$("#containerVenda").block({ message: "Block" });
```

I want to do a IF statement to know if the DIV is blocked or not.

Comment: [This plug-in](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/)

Comment: This plugin exists on, http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#options, so I just want to know if my container is already blocked or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looked into the plugin's code, and it seems it doesn't expose any methods to test if an element is blocked or not. However, it sets some data to the element, which you could try checking. Something like this:

```
var blockableElement = $("#containerVenda").block({ message: "Block" });
alert("Is blocked? " + blockableElement.data('blockUI.isBlocked'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Not documented, but `$("#containerVenda").data('blockUI.isBlocked')` seems to be the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

not sure but try this : http://jquery.malsup.com/block/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#containerVenda").blockUI({ 
         onBlock: function() { 
            $("#containerVenda").addClass("blocked");
             } 
         }); 

     $("#mybutton").click(function(){
        if($("#containerVenda").hasClass("blocked")){ 
          alert("containerVenda is blocked");
        }
      })
})
```

Comment: Correct. In stead of the alert, set some variable that you can read to determine the state

Comment: But I need put a IF statement in a click event that exists for a button in my page. The IF will test if my container is already blocked or not.

Comment: When I tryied this one, I got an error. blockUI is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the classes that were applied to the element containerVenda after you made it block(). See what was added. Than do a check

```
var elem = $("#containerVenda");
if( elem.hasClass("theAddedClass") ){
   //I am a block thingy already.
}
```

Comment: Actually, Block does not actually add any class to the target element.

Comment: @epascarello `hasClass` don't start with dot

Comment: @mgraph whoops! Posted before my morning coffee! :) fixed